# Lossless Join Decomposition Criteria

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

On Wikipedia, it says:

The decomposition is a lossless-join decomposition of R if at least one of the following functional dependencies are in 
F+ (where 
F+ stands for the closure for every attribute or attribute sets in 
F):

```
R1 ∩ R2 → R1 or R1 ∩ R2 → R2
```

Unfortunately, I do not understand this criteria. It is known that the decomposition is lossless if the join of R1 and R2 is R, but how is this derivable from the criteria above?

Comment: That article is wrong in multiple ways. The quote is corrected by starting it "A **binary** decomposition is a lossless-join decomposition of R **into R1 & R2 iff/when** ..." & ending it "(where F+ stands for the closure **of cover F for the FDs that hold in R**)".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proof.

(⇐) Suppose T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub> → T<sub>1</sub> ∈ F<sup>+</sup>. Let *r* a valid instance of R⟨T, F⟩, and *s* = π <sub>T<sub>1</sub></sub>(*r* ) ⨝ π <sub>T<sub>2</sub></sub>(*r* ). If *t* ∈ *s*, then we need to show that *t* ∈ *r*.
By definition of *s*, we have two tuples *u* and *v* in *r* such that *u* [T<sub>1</sub>] = *t* [T<sub>1</sub>], *v* [T<sub>2</sub>] = *t* [T<sub>2</sub>] and *u* [T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub>] = *v* [T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub>] = *t* [T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub>]. Since T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub> → T<sub>1</sub> ∈ F<sup>+</sup>, then *u* [T<sub>1</sub>] = *v* [T<sub>1</sub>] and so *t* = *v*.

The case T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub> → T<sub>2</sub> ∈ F<sup>+</sup> can be proved in the same way.

(⇒) Suppose that, for each valid instance *r* of R⟨T,F⟩, *r* = π <sub>T<sub>1</sub></sub>(*r* ) ⨝ π <sub>T<sub>2</sub></sub>(*r* ); we need to show that T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub> → T<sub>1</sub> ∈ F<sup>+</sup> or T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub> → T<sub>2</sub> ∈ F<sup>+</sup>.

Using reductio ad absurdum, we suppose that none of the two functional dependencies is implied by F.
Let W = (T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub>)<sup>+</sup>, Y<sub>1</sub> = T<sub>1</sub> − W and Y<sub>2</sub> = T<sub>2</sub> − W. Y<sub>1</sub> and Y<sub>2</sub> are not empty by hypothesis, and W, Y<sub>1</sub> and Y<sub>2</sub> are a partition of T.
For each A<sub>i</sub> ∈ T, 1 ≤ i ≤ k, we consider two values a<sub>i</sub>, a<sub>i</sub>′ ∈ dom(A<sub>i</sub>), such that a<sub>i</sub> ≠ a<sub>i</sub>′. Let’s build a relation *r* with attributes WY<sub>1</sub>Y<sub>2</sub> constituted by the two tuples:

e<sub>1</sub>[A<sub>i</sub>] = a<sub>i</sub>, 1 ≤ i ≤ k

e<sub>2</sub>[A<sub>i</sub>] =  a<sub>i</sub> if A<sub>i</sub> ∈ W; a<sub>i</sub>′  if A<sub>i</sub> ∈ Y<sub>1</sub>Y<sub>2</sub>

*r* satisfies each dependency V → Z ∈ F. In fact, if V ⊈ W, then e<sub>1</sub>[V] ≠ e<sub>2</sub>[V], and *r* obviously satisfies the dependency. If V ⊆ W, then (T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub>) → V, so (T<sub>1</sub> ∩ T<sub>2</sub>) → Z for transitivity, from which Z ⊆ W, and so e<sub>1</sub>[Z] = e<sub>2</sub>[Z], an this implies that *r* satifies the dependency. Moreover, since Y<sub>1</sub> and Y<sub>2</sub> are not empty, π <sub>T<sub>1</sub></sub> (*r* ) and π <sub>T<sub>2</sub></sub> (*r* ) contain two tuples and their natural join contains four tuples, more than those of r:

π <sub>T<sub>1</sub></sub> (*r* ) ⨝ π <sub>T<sub>2</sub></sub> (*r* )

contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: See my comment on the question. Also you have unicode characters here that are not in standard or common sets. Eg `e1[Ai] = ai, 1 ≤ i ≤ k `.